# Can I use firestore free for my standalone application react native expo

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I finish my one app and I try to make standalone app and send to users
This android app is my 1st time
I want to know is firebase firestore is free or not
what need to do more
I store data in firestore
if this app use in public ,what are requirement
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. By default, a project on firebase uses the free Spark Plan. It offers some limited services for free. You can check the details [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)